# Firestore cloud functions - access variable in path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I have this architecture in my db : `test1/{test1Id}/test2/{test2Id}`

I want to interact with my DB in cloud functions whenever a new one is added :

```
exports.test = functions.firestore
  .document('test1/{test1Id}/test2/{test2Id}')
  .onCreate(async (testsnap, context) => {
    console.log(testsnap.id);
    console.log(test1Id);
  });
```

but `test1Id` is then `undefined`. How can I access it ?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: As Jonathan answered, the parameters are under `context.params`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must use

```
context.params.test1Id
```

All parameters are held under the context object